# How to Remove and update in one obj of child obj in JSON Using mysql

Tags: mysql

Given the following JSON stored inside a MySQL **json** data type:

```
var data = '   [
        {
        "key": 1, 
        "step": 6, 
        "param": [
                 {"key_1": "test1"},
                 {"key_2": "test2"},
                 {"key_3": "test3"}
                 ] 
        }, 
        {
        "key": 4,
        "step": 8, 
        "param": [
                {"key_4": "test4"},
                {"key_5": "test5"}
                ]
        }
        ]';
```

I need to remove `key_3` in param obj also update removed data in mysql using one query.

**Note:**I Don't know the `key_3` equal value, I Have only `key_1` want to remove {"key_1":"test1"}

**OUTPUT**

```
[
       {
        "key": 1, 
        "step": 6, 
        "param": [                 
                 {"key_2": "test2"},
                 {"key_3": "test3"}
                 ] 
        }, 
        {
        "key": 4,
        "step": 8, 
        "param": [
                {"key_4": "test4"},
                {"key_5": "test5"}
                ]
        }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the function JSON_REMOVE in your attempts to achieve what you want?

Comment: Yes, I tried with JSON_REMOVE  but its also working for parent obj ex:"step",but i need to remove child element

Comment: What does the query look like? How are you pathing to the 'key_1'?